# Enable remote access from one custom IP to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a VPS with installed Elasticsearch. the question is how it will be possible to connect this remote machine with my home IP? I know that with simple line possible to allow all connections, but it is not secure. When I try to add my custom IP, the ES is closed localhost connection and doesn't start properly.

Thank you in any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `network.host` in `elasticsearch.yml` to the VPS public IP address, not localhost. Next you would need to open port 9200 (or whichever you are using) to you home computers specific IP address. So assuming your VPS is Linux you would achieve this by whitelisting your IP address in Iptables and opening this port to that IP address only.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <source> --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT`

As to how secure this would be. In general the recommendations I've seen floating around are mostly agreeing on the fact that it's a good idea to only allow local connections to your elasticsearch instance. If you want to try allowing remote connections for testing purposes, then as I've mentioned it is enough to bind your public IP instead of localhost in `elasticsearch.yml` and opening the appropriate ports.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Put my IP to elasticsearch.yml, trying to add IP to whitelist, but it failed to start. Elasticsearch doesn't allow localhost and my IP. Seems in trouble in adding IP to whitelist

Comment: Cool it works properly, I made mistake adding my home ip. Thank you again

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for etarhan again. One important thing, please check your iptables (firewall) rules before production for opening port for any external IPs. If they allow any remote connection anybody can update, delete your elasticsearch clusters. I solved it by following above instruction, opened remote connection to my home IP but closed any others:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s <source --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9200 -j DROP
```